How to expose a Kubernetes pod running under Azure VM
I have an Azure VM running ubuntu 22.04, I installed kind Kubernetes cluster as a Docker container inside the VM and deployed few pods on the k8s.
Now I would like to access some of the pods via public IP of VM.
I tried following steps:

The Kubernetes Cluster is re-created with something like below. My Pod is running on port 8080 and I would like to expose it to port 31190.

kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 8080
    hostPort: 31190
    protocol: TCP


For the k8s manifest files for the required pods, I specified service type = NodeType and assigned the port

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  type: NodePort  # Specifies the service type as NodePort
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  ports:
    - port: 8080             # The port on which the service is exposed internally
      targetPort: 8080        # The port on the container where the application is running
      nodePort: 31190         # The specific NodePort to expose the service externally 


Azure VM >> NSG firewall, allowed following traffic.


HTTP (TCP 80)
TCP Port 31190

But I am still not able to access the POD from outside e.g., http://<<VM_Public_IP>>:31190
How can I set up this correctly?
Note that I am trying to do this for learning purposes, this is not a production project.

May I know is there a reason why you are deploying the cluster inside the VM if it's for learning purpose only? You can deploy a k8s cluster directly on Azure right? Are you able to curl it from inside the VM?

@Arko - Yes as mentioned in the question, this is purely from learning purpose as my local system does not allow me to install docker so I used Azure VM (with free subscription) to test it out everything. Next, I will go through the steps by steps as you suggested and update on this. Thanks !!

Your steps are correct however this seems to be troubleshooting issue.  We can match step by step and see if everything is fine in your setup. Assuming you have enabled your docker and install Kind on the VM

Create a Kind configuration file with port mappings.
cat <<EOF > kind-config.yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 8080
    hostPort: 31190
    protocol: TCP
EOF


Create the Kind cluster using this configuration
kind create cluster --name my-cluster --config kind-config.yaml


Deploy nginx
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx


Service for nginx
cat <<EOF > nginx-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31190
EOF


Test connectivity from the VM

Additionally, I would recommend you once check the following parameters for better clarity
first your pod logs
example-
kubectl logs nginx-76d6c9b8c-nzhhg

check your nsg rule list once again
az network nsg rule list --resource-group arkorg --nsg-name LinuxVM-nsg --query "[?destinationPortRange=='31190']"


check your IP Tables

If the rule is not present, manually add them to allow forwarding traffic for this port.
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 31190 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 31190 -j ACCEPT


or check if docker is binding the port correctly or not
docker ps | grep my-cluster-control-plane




Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Kind doesn't use image files in any part of its configuration and output; can you [edit] this answer to replace the images with plain text as appropriate?  Also consider if it's possible to cut this down to a smaller set of steps, and if you're really answering a programming-related question.

Sure. Will crop them out. Thanks.
